# A model in Peewee is not empty after creation

Tags: python, peewee

I have a model that has a field named `data` of type `jsonb`:

```python
class Post(Model):
    ...
    data: Dict[str,Any] = BinaryJSONField(default={},
        constraints=[Check("jsonb_typeof(data) = 'object'")])
```

Then, in two different test cases, I create posts, and somehow it happens that in second test I see data from first test in `post.data` immediately after creation.

```python
post = Post()
print(post.data)
# This prints {} in first test but a non-empty dict in second test
```

Where should I look for the problem?

---

Not like it surprises me (it's the most sensible semi-explanation of this), but I just found out that `id(post.data)` of the newly created instance is the same number as in the previous test. So Peewee literally returns me a field of an old object instead of the new one. I now suspect some sort of bug in Peewee's caching or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally a bad practice to use a mutable object ("{}") as a keyword argument. I'd suggest changing the default to None.

Comment: Yes! That was the problem, exactly! I replaced it with `lambda: {}`, I suppose it solves it too, right?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my model I have a 1-many association, so I created a list like this: `allTemperatures = []`.
But if I create a new model (`t = TemperaturesModel()`) the array of the new object was filled with the last values.

Changing to: `allTemperatures = None` solves the problem.